# Symbol’s value as variable is void: last-command-char when trying to insert bracket

Tags: latex, aquamacs

I am using aquamacs and latex mode, 'Symbol’s value as variable is void: last-command-char when trying to insert bracket' occurs when I am trying to insert a bracket.

How could I do, thank you

Comment: Do you use AUCTeX? In any case, you should provide more information on how to reproduce the problem. Do you have custom settings in your init file? If so, you should not load it in order to see if the problem persists also in that case. I don't know how to do it with aquamacs, though.

Answer (score 6):

`last-command-char` was a variable made obsolete in Emacs-19.34 when it was replaced by `last-command-event` (because in older Emacsen, events were only characters).  It was finally removed in Emacs-24.

So some Elisp code you're using still refers to that variable and needs to be updated.  Just `grep` for that name in your files to see which thing needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed it and compile the new file, and the problem is solved.